# GCP regional static external IP limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

I couldn't correct statement on Google cloud documents about external static IP address limit.

In my projects I would have more than 200 external IP requires for https load balancers. Does anyone know what are hard limit on GCP project for static external IP's?

Or how many external static IP',s I can reserve?
Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GCP usually the starting quota is 200 external IPs, but you can request an increase provided you can show a valid use case.

There are probably upper constraints which vary by time and region.

Comment: It seems like this is soft limit. Is there any hard limit for this?

Comment: There is no published hard limit per organization. Your limit will probably be decided by available resources in the specific region.  In our our account, we've had limits in the >1000 area.